# Why does the POST call from my Angular Application does not work, but with Postman there is no Problem?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

The Problem:

I do a call for localhost:8081/images with method POST. It should upload an image to an S3 and save the information on my database. As result I get some meta information like the URL and the ID of the Database. I use a Bearer token for Auth and the call needs 700ms for executing with Postman.

Get calls are working with Angular, but not Post calls. It is not possible that I call the API wrong since I use the openapi generator for my client. The application is written API first.

When I call my API localhost:8081/images with method POST from Angular it executes my code in the spring boot application. This means it writes the image to the s3 and it creates the entry in the database. So I am guessing, it could not be a CORS error. Also in the console I can't see anything about CORS.

My console log is:

```
FetchError: The request failed and the interceptors did not return an alternative response
    at BusinessApi.<anonymous> (main.js:4434:21)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (:8100/vendor.js:129742:24)
    at _throw (:8100/vendor.js:129768:9)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:8260:160)
    at Object.onInvoke (:8100/vendor.js:103229:25)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:8260:48)
    at Zone.run (polyfills.js:7986:37)
    at polyfills.js:9406:28
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:8293:173)
```

So what could be the problem? Since my spring boot application works like expected and also is secured etc. I guess my problem is from Angular.

```
this.imageApi.createImage(imageRequest).then((data: any) => {
   
      let imageId = data.id
      let businessRequest = {
        name: this.business.name,
        description: this.business.description,
        logo: imageId
      } as BusinessRequest
      let body = { businessRequest: businessRequest } as CreateBusinessRequest
      this.businessApi.createBusiness(body).then((data: BusinessResponse) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.router.navigate(['/business', data.id, 'manager']);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Business not created")
        console.log(error)
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Image not created")
      console.log(error)
    }
    )
```

In my log I can find Image not created.
If I only set the Business Request I get : Business not created.

It seems failing for all POST calls.
[image: The Headers of my Call in Developer console]

This one is in Preview and Response:
[image]

Request Payload is set correctly:
[image]

Postman Call:
[image]

Postman curl:
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8081/images' 
--header 'Origin: http://localhost:8100/' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciO....rVZAA' 
--form 'media=@"/C:/Users/info/Downloads/image.jpg"'

(Bearer token is cutted by myself and set correctly)

Edit: Additional information, if i debug my kotlin application it starts my breakpoint, but instead of waiting in the angular application it already fails. Could it be something with preflight request?

Comment: Don’t post images for couple of reasons: 1) Not searchable 2) can’t be copied if someone wants to reproduce the issue. In addition, we need to see the HTTP requests made by Postman vs Angular.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar added the postman informations to it. Added a curl also for Postman. All inoformations from my images can't be used for reproducing the error (code is in text) and it's no information included that can help for searching. Also would it be too many characters for one question

Comment: There's no such thing as "too many characters". There's no penalty for posting a lengthy question.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar my bad, this was for the title

Comment: Your Postman request is sending data as `multipart/form-data`, whereas your Angular code is sending data as JSON. Can your `/business` endpoint actually accept JSON? If not, this is probably why the request fails.

Comment: @Helen as I mentioned in my question i use the openapi generator => data is sent correctly (unless there would be a bug in openapi). Also the POST call is for /business and /images executed correctly and the data is safed to the database

Comment: Check browser console for errors, you may have to enable `show cors errors` and `log xmlhttprequests` first.

Comment: @kemsky both is activated

Comment: It is certainly an issue from angular's end:
1) Check if OPTIONS request is allowed
2) I haven't used the openapi gen, so I would double check if you are sending the request properly. 
Also, your token is posted in the first image, remove it if it is sensitive

Comment: Your postman call is to /images and your angular call is to /business - comparing the results is pointless. Can you show a call to /images from postman?

Comment: it's looks like you have a problem in your "interceptor" (when add the token not return `return next.handle(authReq);` or similar). Check also if you send a json or a plain text

Answer (score 0):

If you use interceptor for the angular application, re check the code by debugging and find the reason. And use a proxy for avoid the Corss.

Comment: I think all cors errors are logged in the console? I don't have cors errors in my console.

Comment: Did you add proxy for the API s

Comment: Yes I tried with a proxy

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with some of the other suggestions here and say that your problem is CORS related. On your controller files, for /business and /images, try using the cross origin annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") -> change with your angular url
```

Comment: no,  cors works. i checked this